# having trouble using std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, libmodbus

I'm having trouble using `std::mutex` ( cpp ) to serialize access to a shared resource
(I need to use libmodbus which is not thread-safe.
I'm currently trying to serialize access to the modbus_write_registers function by placing a `mutex.lock()` statement before it. I release the mutex near the end of my function.)

the essence of my problem is that it looks like several threads are able to acquire a lock on a mutex simultaneously.

I've tried several different compiler versions, I've tried using `std::lock_guard` the results are the same.

here are some technicals :

```
gcc 7.4.0   ( 6.3.0 , 5.4.0)
libstdc++.so.6.0.26
building with cmake , 
c++ version 14 (set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14"))
```

some code :

my write function

```
std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

m.lock()

std::cout << "@@@@@@@@@@ FfrModBusClient::setRegistersOnePacket after lock tid " << this_id << std::endl;

ModbusRetCode = modbus_write_registers(pToModbusServer, AddressToWrite, RegsToWrite, RegsValues);

std::cout << "FfrModBusClient::setRegistersOnePacket after modbus_write & before sleep,  id " <<  this_id << std::endl;
```

my main :

```
struct TestThreadParameters
{
    int               Id;
    FfrModBusClient * pSharedModbusClient;
    int               Port;
    std::string       Ip;

};

void TestInThread(const TestThreadParameters Parameters)
.
.
.

void main :
TestThreadParameters    TTP;
TTP.Ip = IPAddress;
TTP.Port = Port;
TTP.pSharedModbusClient = &ModbusClientObject;
std::thread a1(TestInThread,TTP);
.
.
std::thread a9(TestInThread,TTP);
a1.join()....
```

- ModbusClientObject is an object of a class that has a `std::mutex` ComLock as a private member, and a "libmodbus" context data member pToModbusServer...
- to the best of my knowledge I'm passing the address of 1 object to all threads,
  I've made sure all threads show the same value for its address at runtime.
  and I don't explicitly create another instance of the Modbus wrapper class anywhere.

my terminal shows successive "after lock" messages with no "after modbus_write & before sleep" messages between them and the matching modbus_write_registers call fail with various memory corruption errors (as expected from a lib that is not thread-safe).

Any help would be appreciated.
:-)
omer

Comment: i'm using pthread 
libpthread-stubs0-dev 0.3-4
as far as i can tell its the currently supported/official version

Comment: Add code to show how `m` is related to your ModbusClientObject object.

Comment: My psychic powers say that `m` is a different object in each thread.

Comment: If you think its your system, make a small example program to simulate the issue. As others have said though, Chances are high its your code, not C++ or the STL.

Comment: m is defined as a private member of the class.
i can show the code , but theres not much to see.

moreover, i've also tried moving its definition to the cpp file , same results :-(

Comment: now tried declaring m as static (and placing definition in .cpp file ) - same results

Comment: With concurrency/multi-threading the devil is in the detail.  You really need to show more code -- preferably a [mcve].

Comment: wrote a minimal example - IT DID NOT REPRODUCE.

any ideas about how to debug the original ?
is there a way to Id the mutex used ?

Comment: Just log the address

Comment: converted all methods in class to use lock_guard,  seems look significantly better now.
could mean that i unlocked somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

after confirming that std::mutex works as expected on my pc,
the only thing that is left is some sort of logical bug where i perform an unlock by mistake.